# To optimize my linq query which listed as top consuming query in azure query performance insight tool

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, azure, azure-sql-database

My Linq query to optimize:

```
var onlineData = (from od in peopleStatus.AsNoTracking().ToList()

let location = (from zone in db.RTLS_ZONEDTLS
                where zone.zone_id == od.Person.Zone_ID
                select zone.area).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault()

let zoneIdsArray = getZoneList((od.ZoneIds.ToArray()))
let fzones = zoneIdsArray.Select(z => z).Take(4)

select new OnlineDataInfoDTO
{
    P_ID = od.Person.PERSONID,
    T_ID = (int)od.Person.TAGID,
    Z_ID = (od.Person.created_time >= startOfThisDay) ? (int)od.Person.Zone_ID : -1,
    LOC = (location != null ? location : " "),
    STATUS = (od.Person.created_time >= startOfThisDay) ? (int)od.Person.status : 6,
    T_BAT_SIG_STR = (int)od.Person.TAG_SIGNALSTRENGTH,
    B_BAT_SIG_STR = (int)od.Person.BS_SIGNALSTRENGTH,
    T_BAT_STA_VAL = (int)od.Person.TAG_BATTERY_STATUS_VAL,
    T_BAT_STA_PERCNT = (int)od.Person.TAG_BATTERY_STATUS_PERCNT,
    BS_BAT_STA_VAL = (int)od.Person.BS_BATTERY_STATUS_VAL,
    BS_BAT_STA_PER = (int)od.Person.BS_BATTERY_STATUS_PERCNT,
    IN_TIME = (od.Person.INTIME).ToString(),
    ALL_NOT_TME = (od.Person.ALLISNOTWELLTIME).ToString(),
    P_TME = (od.Person.PANICTIME).ToString(),
    NO_M_TME = (od.Person.NOMOTIONTIME).ToString(),
    OUT_TME = (od.Person.OUT_TIME).ToString(),
    TEMP_TME = (od.Person.TEMPEXCEEDTIME).ToString(),
    LOW_BAT_TME = (od.Person.LOW_BATTERY_TIME).ToString(),
    FOUT_TME = (od.Person.FOUT_TIME).ToString(),
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME = (od.Person.LASTUPDATEDTIME).ToString(),
    TEMP_VAL = (decimal)(od.Person.TEMP_VALUE),


    NO_OF_OUT = (
      from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
      where (o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowBattery)
      where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
      where (o.PERSON_ID.ToLower() == od.Person.PERSONID.ToLower())
      select o.fltname).Count(),
    NO_OF_PANIC = (
      from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
      where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.Panic
      where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
      where (o.PERSON_ID.ToLower() == od.Person.PERSONID.ToLower())
      select o.fltname).Count(),
    NO_OF_IN_ACTIVE = (
      from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
      where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.InActive
      where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
      where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
      select o.fltname).Count(),
    NO_OF_TEMP = (
      from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
      where (o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.HighTemp || o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowTemp)
      where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
      where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
      select o.fltname).Count(),
    NO_OF_LBAT = (
      from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
      where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowBattery
      where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
      where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
      select o.fltname).Count(),
    LOCS = fzones.ToList()
}).ToList();
```

And my getZoneList method looks like below which was used in the above query.

```
public int[] getZoneList(decimal[] zoneIdsArray)
{
    int[] zoneIds = Array.ConvertAll(zoneIdsArray, x => (int)x);
    List<int> list = zoneIds.ToList();
    for (int c = 1; c < zoneIdsArray.Count(); c++)
    {
        if (zoneIdsArray[c] == zoneIdsArray[c - 1])
        {
            list.Remove((int)zoneIdsArray[c]);
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

For my application i had written a web-service using WebApi2 in visual studio-2015, with Entity framework as ORM and Azure_SQL as backend. I have observed that **above linq query taking minimum 25 secs to maximum 1.5 mins to execute** (used azure portal's  query performance insight tool to find it).
After commenting and testing line by line code along with time, I came to know that

```
from od in peopleStatus.AsNoTracking().ToList()
```

This line taking so much time(average 55 seconds). I cant skip to convert into List to use further. Suggest me what should i do to optimize my query to decrease my overall turnaround time.

Comment: try to take such as NO_OF_OUT's value caculation logic out?

Comment: I made it outside but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have reduced my query execution time from 55 seconds to on an average 4.5 seconds by removing **AsNoTracking().ToList().**

Old query which was taken too much time to execute.

```
  var onlineData = from od in peopleStatuc.AsNoTracking().ToList()
```

New query by which my total turnaround time decreased highly.

```
  var onlineData = from od in peopleStats
```

I found that unnecessarily i was converting my results into list(time to convert results into list increases as records get increases) while executing subqueries, so removed that.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, this code

```
 NO_OF_OUT = (from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
                                                       where (o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowBattery)
                                                       where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
                                                       where (o.PERSON_ID.ToLower() == od.Person.PERSONID.ToLower())
                                                       select o.fltname).Count(),
                                          NO_OF_PANIC = (from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
                                                         where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.Panic
                                                         where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
                                                         where (o.PERSON_ID.ToLower() == od.Person.PERSONID.ToLower())
                                                         select o.fltname).Count(),
                                          NO_OF_IN_ACTIVE = (from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
                                                             where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.InActive
                                                             where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
                                                             where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
                                                             select o.fltname).Count(),
                                          NO_OF_TEMP = (from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
                                                        where (o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.HighTemp || o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowTemp)
                                                        where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
                                                        where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
                                                        select o.fltname).Count(),
                                          NO_OF_LBAT = (from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
                                                        where o.faultno == (int)Constants.Faults.LowBattery
                                                        where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
                                                        where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
                                                        select o.fltname).Count(),
```

does basically the same, the only difference is what faultno you want to count by. You can try to use group by faultno and get them all at once.

EDIT:
Linq is not my strong suit, but perhaps this will work:

```
from o in db.RTLS_FAULT_DTLS
            where (startOfThisDay <= o.ORC_DATETIME && o.ORC_DATETIME <= todayEndDate)
            where (o.PERSON_ID == od.Person.PERSONID)
            group o by o.faultno
            into g
            select new
            {
                faultno = g.Key,
                count = g.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. Can u please post code how to do that in my case I want to calculate total count for individual faults with fault number in required time interval only.

Comment: Thank u for ur response but nothing improved. Again I had commented all that count related code still there is no much improvement.

Comment: Hmm. You could try to measure what is actually your bottleneck in the code. Stopwatch is your friend there for basic measurements [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx). Let me know when you have some timings for your code.

Comment: Dear @lubos Hemala i found that this(  from od in peopleStatus.AsNoTracking().ToList() ) line taking too much time to execute.

Comment: Since I don't know your code in detail, I can't really help you there.